# Absolute div inside the Relative div position right 0 doesn't work properly?

Tags: css

I have an absolute div inside a relative div positioned div.

This usually works as it should but in this case, the absolute div sits on the right but when I resize the screen, the absolute div wont stay at the right:0; position and I don't understand why.

This is a [WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9hwqdz4m/)

If you resize the 'result' section of the the fiddle above and make it small, you will see the issue.

This is my CSS code:

```
.pDiv {
    float:left;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    position:relative;
    margin:8px;
    border-radius:4px;
    display:inline-block;

}


.pDiv img {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    border-radius:4px;

}
```

and I mainly have the rest of the CSS code inline.

Can someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show all relevant code here. Move inline-styles to the css section properly.

Comment: It is working properly, what you are calling "problem" it is only that when you resize smaller the scroll bar needs to appear.

Comment: Any reason why you have `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` on the same element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled the position part of the `#thumbnail-outter`:

```
position;relative;
```

Should be colon `:` instead of semicolon `;` after "position".

```
position: relative;
```

`#cameraCon` also has a `right: 20px` and a `margin-right: -10px`. Remove that if you want the element to align perfectly at the right.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hwqdz4m/2/)